# Linuxの架空commandで出力した値をsedを使わずにするにはどうしたら良いでしょう？

Tags: linux, command-line, sed

架空のLinux command、例えば"imagestatus"があったとして、

```
imagestatus *.jpg
```

とすれば、

```
File: sampleimg1.jpg
Resolution: 720 x 547
Channels: 3
Channel Types: RGB without Alpha

File: sampleimg2.jpg
Resolution: 2048 x 1556
Channels: 4
Channel Types: RGB without Alpha

File: sampleimg3.jpg
Resolution: 2048 x 1556
Channels: 5
Channel Types: RGB without Beta
...
```

が出るとします。コレを以下のようにFile: Resolutionのフォーマットにして改行したいです。

```
sampleimg1.jpg: 720 x 547
sampleimg2.jpg: 2048 x 1556 
sampleimg3.jpg: 2048 x 1556
...
```

現在、以下のようなコードにしていますが、二つ目に行く前の改行が上手くいかず、Resolutionと次のFileの前に「:」が入ってしまいます。

```
echo "$(<sampleFile.txt )" | \
awk '{FS=": "}{if ($1 ~ "File|Resolution") {print $2} }' |  perl -pe 's/\n/: /'

結果：
sampleimg1.jpg: 720 x 547: sampleimg2.jpg: 2048 x 1556: sampleimg3.jpg: 2048 x 1556:
```

Macを使っているので改行の調整にsedは可能な限り使いたくないのですが、もしMacを使っている方でsedの書き方を知っている方がおればお教えください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これでよくないですか

```
BEGIN { FS=": " }
$1 == "File" { printf("%s: ", $2) }
$1 == "Resolution" { printf("%s\n", $2) }
```

Answer (score 0):

`File:`の行でファイル名をおぼえておいて、`Resolution:`の行で、ファイル名とリゾリューションを出力するのはいかがでしょうか。

```
awk ' /^File:/{file = $2} /^Resolution:/{printf("%s: %s %s %s\n", file, $2, $3, $4)} '
```